# Recharts value at pointer to show in tooltip?

Tags: recharts

Is it possible in Recharts to show a Horizontal line at the Y location where the user has their mouse over and retrieve that Y value so we can display it on the Tooltip?

https://meridian.a2z.com/components/tooltip/?platform=react-web

I've been trying to do some research into how we could get the Y value on the graph where the mouse is hovering or clicked, but I'm having trouble seeing where we could even pull that out.

Any tips on attributes or components we could use to grab this data? Is it even something we have access to from the library?

To clarify, we're trying to get the value of the Y axis at where the user has their cursor over the graph.

So if the graph looks like this and the user has their mouse at the pink dot location, I would be trying to grab out the value of ~7000 - what the y value would be at that graph location [image: cursor location]

Comment: I don't think that Y value exists in the chart as anything except for an SVG x,y coordinate. The only points that are accessible are the data points you provide via the `payload` prop being passed to `<Tooltip />`. Giving the hovered x,y coordinates at the scale of the chart would have to be a new feature of Recharts.

Comment: Did you managed to solve your issue? I have a similar problem and I cannot find a way to get the yAxis value on mouse events

Comment: @Zoti gotcha!) I try to find it everywhere, I mentioned you on github

Comment: Hey @deathfry, I've answered on GitHub too. Sadly I never managed to solve this. I ended up opening a proposal to recharts: https://github.com/recharts/recharts/issues/2283

Comment: @Zoti I am new to this, but it seems activeLabel is stored in generateCategoricalChart.tsx in recharts. Is it possible to fork it and change and then make a PR so Y coordinate will be available?

Comment: I don't have a clue. The proposal was for an `activeYLabel` in order to work with `yAxis`. You can tag/ask `xile611` on the proposal thread if there was any progress.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit:

**Note about responsiveness:**
If you want to make this responsive, just adjust the chartBounds based on the padding/margin you've applied to the chart component and you should be good to go.

If you're trying something more advanced and need the height and width to pass to the chart component for more calculations, the following article should help: https://www.pluralsight.com/tech-blog/getting-size-and-position-of-an-element-in-react/

---

**NOTE: This is a bit of a hack and may not be a perfect solution but it should be enough to get you on the right track**

You should be able to use the chartX and chartY fields from onMouseMove. Unfortunately, this is just the pixel value under the cursor but you should be able to translate it into the range you are using for your graph.

Here is an example put together using the SimpleLineChart example recharts has up. This should work if you just want to get the Y value under the user's cursor and can be extended to get the X value as well.

```
const {LineChart, Line, XAxis, YAxis, CartesianGrid, Tooltip, Legend} = Recharts;
const data = [
      {name: 'Page A', uv: 4000, pv: 2400, amt: 2400},
      {name: 'Page B', uv: 3000, pv: 1398, amt: 2210},
      {name: 'Page C', uv: 2000, pv: 9800, amt: 2290},
      {name: 'Page D', uv: 2780, pv: 3908, amt: 2000},
      {name: 'Page E', uv: 1890, pv: 4800, amt: 2181},
      {name: 'Page F', uv: 2390, pv: 3800, amt: 2500},
      {name: 'Page G', uv: 3490, pv: 4300, amt: 2100},
];


//The pixel bounds for the LineChart, 0,0 is the top left corner
// these were found using the inspector built into the web browser
// these are in pixels but correspond to the values used in your graph
// so 246 is 0 Y on the graph and 5 is 10000 Y on the graph (according to your data)
const chartBoundsY = {min: 246, max: 5}

// The bounds we are using for the chart
const chartMinMaxY = {min: 0, max: 10000}

// Convert the pixel value from the cursor to the scale used in the chart
const remapRange = value => {
  let fromAbs = value - chartBoundsY.min
  let fromMaxAbs =  chartBoundsY.max - chartBoundsY.min      

  let normal = fromAbs / fromMaxAbs

  let toMaxAbs = chartMinMaxY.max - chartMinMaxY.min
  let toAbs = toMaxAbs * normal

  return Math.ceil(toAbs + chartMinMaxY.min)
}

const SimpleLineChart = React.createClass({
  render () {
    return (
      <LineChart 
        width={600} height={300} data={data}
        margin={{top: 5, right: 30, left: 20, bottom: 5}}
        onMouseMove={props => {
          // We get the values passed into the onMouseMove event 
          if(props.isTooltipActive) {
            // If the tooltip is active then we display the Y value 
            // under the mouse using our custom mapping
            console.log(remapRange(props.chartY))
          }
        }}    
      >
       <XAxis dataKey="name"/>
       <YAxis/>
       <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3"/>
       <Tooltip/>
       <Legend />
       <Line type="monotone" dataKey="pv" stroke="#8884d8" activeDot={{r: 8}}/>
       <Line type="monotone" dataKey="uv" stroke="#82ca9d" />
      </LineChart>
    )
  }
})

ReactDOM.render(
  <SimpleLineChart />,
  document.getElementById('container')
)
```

You can open this example in jsfiddle and paste in the code above in the JS editor to try it out for yourself. http://recharts.org/en-US/examples

Here is the documentation for the mouse event for the LineChart: http://recharts.org/en-US/api/LineChart

Comment: How did you come up with ```const chartBoundsY = {min: 246, max: 5}```? K-Log@

Comment: Just using the inspector built into the browser. I looked at the placement of the chart and grabbed those pixel coords so that i could remap pixels in the browser window to coordinates in the chart using the remapRangeFunction.

Comment: Ah, I guess I'll have to find a way to do it programmatically on our side since we are using a Responsive Container

Comment: @CustardBun I updated my answer with a note about responsiveness that should help you.

Comment: @CustardBun have you find an answer? Please share it

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with the axis scale option together with d3's invert method.
The following code excerpt should give you an idea.

```
const domainY = d3.extent(data, d => d[keyY])
const scaleY = d3.scaleLinear().domain(domainY).range([0, 1])

<AreaChart
 onMouseDown={(e) => console.log(scaleY.invert(e.chartY))}
 ...

<YAxis
 domain={['auto', 'auto']}
 dataKey={keyY}
 type="number"
 scale={scaleY}
 ...
```

Comment: could you please provide an example? What is a range of [0,1]? This did not worked for me(