# Recharts square zoom implementation

Tags: recharts

The sample I am talkin' about is here

https://recharts.org/en-US/examples/HighlightAndZoomLineChart
and here
https://codesandbox.io/s/highlight-zomm-line-chart-v77bt

Please press left button of the mouse and drag it to the right - this is how zoom is currently done. Please take a look at the `activeLabel` variable.

Currently recharts could make a zoom into the graph by passing the x coordinate (which is stored in `activeLabel` variable) and zooom looks like a pillar all over the y coordinate.

I want to select an area - square or rectangle to make more customized zoom. The trouble is that I can't get the y value of the graph (not pixel in window). Recharts gives only x coordinate of the graph, but not y.

I've searched all over the issues on gitHub, mailed the creator with no luck.

I've read the
[Recharts value at pointer to show in tooltip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63585743/recharts-value-at-pointer-to-show-in-tooltip/63679353#comment126915061_63679353)

but I could not get how could I count the initial values of chartX and chartY in my responsive container, so it is very depends on the window user has.

Please help me to find a solution to match chartY in pixels to my real values in my chart depending on Responsive Container I am using.

Comment: it seems I found it...will post later

Answer (score 1):

Zoom can be done by using the mouse events of the chart.

You can store the values in a state then call the zoom function on onMouseUp.
And in zoom function, you can set the domains of the axes.
Don't forget to set the axes to `allowDataOverflow`.
And you can also draw the rectangle by using `ReferenceArea`

```
function zoom () {
    setXAxisBoundaries([rectangle[0], rectangle[1]])
    setYAxisBoundaries([rectangle[2], rectangle[3]])
}
```

```
<ScatterChart
    onMouseDown={(event) => setRectangle([event.xValue, event.yValue])}
    onMouseMove={(event) => setRectangle(rectangle => [...rectangle, event.xValue, event.yValue]))}
    onMouseUp={zoom}>
```

```
<XAxis
    dataKey="x"
    allowDataOverflow
    domain={xAxisBoundaries}
    type="number" />
<YAxis
    dataKey="y"
    allowDataOverflow
    domain={yAxisBoundaries}
    type="number" />
```